# How to use a Google Cloud Task Queue and get a json response?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I would like to use Google Cloud Task Queue in my firebase cloud function to call another function and return the work.  Is this something we can do with Google Cloud Task?

I am trying to do something similar such as Redis queue where once the work is done I can get the results and continue with my app.

Here I am trying to show what I want to do with a simple addition function.  In reality, I would like to call another Http endpoint and use my Queue to rate limit request. For now, this example gets the point across however I cant seem to send the data back.

```js
exports.addNumbersFunc = functions.https.onRequest(async (data, res) => {

  const payload = data.body;
  console.log("Received: ", payload);

  // Work done
  const answer = payload["numbers"]["a"] + payload["numbers"]["b"];

  // Can I send back the answer here?
  res.json({ "answer": answer });

}
);


exports.exampleFunction1 = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {

  // create json object to send to server with data
  const jsonPayload = JSON.stringify({
    "numbers": { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
  });

  const url =
    `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/addNumbersFunc`;

  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: Buffer.from(jsonPayload).toString('base64')
    }, oidcToken: {
      serviceAccountEmail
    }
  };

  const request = {
    parent: parent,
    task: task,
  };

  // Send create task request.
  console.log('Sending task:');  
  const [response] = await client.createTask(request);

  console.log(`Response: ${response}`);
  console.log(`Created task ${response.name}`);

  // Would the response be here??
  console.log(`Response httpReques: ${response.httpRequest.body}`);

  return response;

});
```

Comment: Cloud Task is async. You cann't get the HTTP response of the task;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Task is async. You cann't get the HTTP response of the task; –
guillaume blaquiere